# Finite difference method approximation to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the ODE $$\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}+4\frac{du}{dx}+4u=0$$
On the interval [0,1]
with the boundary conditions $u=1$ when $x=0$ and $u=0$ when $x=1$.

If h denotes the step size, the finite difference approximation to the ODE at the $i^{th}$ grid point is 
 $$\left(\frac{1}{h^2}+\frac{2}{h}\right){u_{i+1}}  -\left(\frac{2}{h^2}-4\right){u_i} + \left(\frac{1}{h^2}-\frac{2}{h}\right){u_{i-1}}$$

How is this derived?

Comment: What does $\left(\frac{2}{h^2}+4\right)_{u_i}$ mean? Makes no sense to me. Or is it just $\left(\frac{2}{h^2}+4\right) u_i$. I believe the right approximation is $$\left(\frac{1}{h^2}+\frac{2}{h}\right) u_{i+1} - \left(\frac{2}{h^2}-4\right) u_{i} + \left(\frac{1}{h^2}-\frac{2}{h}\right) u_{i-1} = 0$$

Comment: It the latter one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will use $$u_j = u(jh), h = 1/n.$$

here are finite difference approximations obtained from the taylor series of $u$ centered at $x = jh.$ they are
$$\frac{du}{dx}\Big|_{x = jh} = \frac{u_{j+1}-u_{j-1}}{2h},\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\Big|_{x = jh} = \frac{u_{j+1}-2u_j + u_{j-1}}{h^2} $$

now you put these in the equation $ \frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}+4\frac{du}{dx}+4u=0.$  you her $$ \frac{u_{j+1}-2u_j + u_{j-1}}{h^2}+ 4 \frac{u_{j+1}-u_{j-1}}{2h}+4u_j = 0$$

you can simplify this and get in a form you have. hope this helps.

Comment: @ abel in my notes I have that j is defined between 2 and N where N is the number of intervals. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

A three point finite difference scheme can approximate the first derivative by the following,

$$ f'_j = \frac{ f_{j+1} - f_{j-1} }{2 h },$$

this approximation is second order accurate.

To get the particular coefficeints being used we write,

$$ f'_j = a f_{j+1} + b f_j + c f_{j-1},$$

we then expand the functions $f_j$'s in a taylor series, for instance,

$$ f_{j+1} = f(x_j+h) = f(x_j) + h f'(x_j) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_j) + O(h^3),$$

which lets us write our approximate derivative as,

$$ f'_j = (a+b+c) f(x_j) + (a-c)h f'(x_j) + (a+c)\frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_j) + O(h^3).$$

This gives us three equations,

$$ a+b+c = 0,$$
$$ a - c = \frac{1}{h},$$ 
$$ a + c = 0,$$

the solution to this system is $a=1/2h, b=0, c=-1/2h$ which is where the approximation comes from.

Comment: There were some mistakes in the original post, which explains the downvote. If the downvoter sees this post, I'd appreciate him/her re-evaluating this answer.